# Get restaurant menu from Page using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The problem is to get the link to menu from a Facebook official page of a restaurant. 
Here is an example of such page: https://www.facebook.com/freshchoice.bb — there is a link to menu of the restaurant which leads to https://www.facebook.com/download/216155385221332/Facebook%20menu.pdf.
Actually, this link works well even if I remove the name of the file from it, and I understand, that 216155385221332 is an ID of some object. But how can I obtain this ID from the API?

I have already spent two days trying to find a solution for this task and have had no luck.
When I request data from Facebook Graph API, I get tons of information, and I can request any of the fields listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page but there is no 'menu', or 'downloads' field, and I have almost broke my brain trying to find out a way to solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to reach this object if you didn't create it yourself.

There's the `restaurant.menu` OpenGraph object:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/restaurant.menu/

but I think only the user who created it can access it programatically.

The page you're referring to probably just uploaded the menu via the Facebook website, and didn't create an OpenGraph object.

Se

- https://www.facebook.com/help/533179700126832

Comment: Yes, I read that documentation section and tried to get restaurant.menu with a page id instead of `/me` — got an error. :(

Comment: Yes, any information displayed on the Page is edited and uploaded by its owner. I only hope there is some way to get that relation between a Page and a menu using API. For example, photos of a restaurant are uploaded by the owner as well, and when I request information about page, I can get field `photos`, which contains an array with IDs of the objects.

Comment: There's no way with the API currently.

Comment: Well, it's a pity. The only way to get that link, as I see it, is to download and parse an entire webpage.

Comment: ...which is not allowed by the Scraping TOS of Facebook